# Git repo build URL with Docker compose

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to use a git repo URL in my `docker-compose.yml` file, as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#git-repositories). The service looks like this:

```yaml
  app:
    build: "https://[MY_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN]@github.com/org/repo.git#develop"
```

I get the following error:

```
$ docker-compose up
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠿ app Error                                                                   0.5s
[+] Building 0.0s (1/1) FINISHED                                                    
 => CACHED [internal] load git source https://[MY_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN]  0.0s
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount730635615/https:/[MY_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN]@github.com/org/repo.git#develop/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

BUT, when I copy the exact URL from my `docker-compose.yml` file, I can use it with Docker build successfully. I can see all steps of the `Dockerfile` being executed.

```
$ docker build https://[MY_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN]@github.com/org/repo.git#develop
```

There is a `develop` branch, `[MY_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN]` is my actual GitHub token, and there is a valid `Dockerfile` (with a capital D) in the repo root. Why would this work with `docker build` but not `docker-compose`? It can't be an issue with the token, since it works with `docker build`.

If it matters, I'm on an M1 Mac with Docker for Mac installed. `docker-compose` is working fine with other services.

Comment: have you tried this?

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3038#issuecomment-292044389

Comment: I get a `Could not resolve host: github.company.com` when using a GitHub personal access token with all scopes. It's in the format `build: "https://ghp_[OMITTED]:@github.company.com/org/repo.git#develop"`. There is no main or master, just `develop` at the moment. Does not work without `#develop` either.

Comment: What version of Docker Compose are you using?

Comment: Does your company have it's own github instance, or are you on github.com?

Comment: `Docker Compose version v2.1.1` @PierreB.
It's an organization repo but it is github.com @BMitch.

Comment: In which case, that suggested URL obviously will not work. Did not see it is `github.company.com` rather than `company.github.com`. So, I think the URL in my post is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Build Docker Image from git repository URL with Docker compose file**

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  ordersvc:
    build:
      context: https://github.com/Omkeshs/e-com.git #git repo link
      dockerfile: ./order/Dockerfile #Dockerfile path in repo
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

  productsvc:
    build:
      context: https://github.com/Omkeshs/e-com.git
      dockerfile: ./product/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

- In my case, I have Created micro-service based architecture(Order-Product services), In the same git repo. both docker images create from a same git repo.

ref - https://github.com/Omkeshs/e-com

Answer (score 0):

**Try#** - removal of double quotes

```
  app:
    build: https://[MY_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN]@github.com/org/repo.git#develop
```

or this with or without double quotes

```
  app:
    build:
      context: https://[MY_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN]@github.com/org/repo.git#develop
```

or this with or without double quotes

```
  app:
    build:
      context: https://[MY_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN]@github.com/org/repo.git#develop
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Same error as in the post with all 3 unfortunately.

Comment: How about the following: 1) install ssh on your container as part of the docker build, 2) setup ssh permissions between your Mac and the git repo, 3) as part of your docker compose configure to mount the directory where your ssh id_rsa key resides as a volume with the containers ssh dir, 4) use 'git@github.com/org/repo.git#develop` as your build config. That way we can seee if it is an issue with docker compose / mac / git configuration, or whether it is related to the oauth token use with docker compose

Comment: Will do. I will also mention, when I just use `git clone https://[MY_GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN]@github.com/org/repo.git` that works fine, but I do have a SSH key setup with my Mac. If I change the token to something else I get an auth error (even with the SSH key, GitHub prefers the provided token). Same happens thing if I try an invalid token with `docker build`, so I think that means the key must be fine.

Comment: Tried giving access to `~/.ssh` as a volume, `- "~/.ssh:/root/ssh:ro"` and `docker build git@github.com:org/repo.git` on my local machine, and both give me this: `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: failed to load cache key: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service moby.sshforward.v1.SSH`. I can `git clone git@github.com:org/repo.git` successfully

Comment: Got an idea, your using Docker Compose v2 which comes with Docker Desktop, wonder is the new version is the issue. Try `docker-compose disable-v2` from the cli, it will force it to use v1. See if that works. You can also disable via Docker Desktop. Select Preferences=>General and untick 'Use Docker Compose V2'